# js slideToggle doesn't work

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle

I'm new to js, so this probably is a beginners problem.

For my mobile website, I want the menu to appear with slideToggle when clicking on a menu icon on the top.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles2.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<title>CSI - Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"/></a>
<div class="menu_icon"><img src="img/menu_icon.png" alt="menu_icon"/></div>

<div class="nav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html"><img src="img/home.png" alt="home"/>Home_</a></li>
            <li><a href="story.html"><img src="img/paper.png" alt="paper"/>Story_</a></li>
            <li><a href="course.html"><img src="img/glass.png" alt="glass"/>Course_</a></li>
            <li><a href="archive.html"><img src="img/archive.png" alt="archive"/>Archive_</a></li>
            <li><a href="facebook.html"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook"/>Discuss with Facebook_</a></li>
            <li><a href="twitter.html"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter"/>Discuss with Twitter_</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".menu_icon").on("click", function(){
        $('.nav').slideToggle();
    });
```

I would like the .nav to show up with slideToggle when clicking the .menu_icon class / image.

Can anyone please help me out?
Thanks in advance!
    });

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? It doesn't look like it

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to add jQuery (as Jeff Shaver noticed) : add

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in your head to load the jQuery library.

Moreover, you forgot to close the `$(document).ready(function(){` with `});` at the end of your code (see **trajce** answer).

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy5KN/) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks! I added jQuery, but it still doesn't work.. Nothing happens when hovering and clicking the image / class. Firebug only shows me the js code, no errors..  I have no idea what else is wrong..

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing, I copy - pasted that wrong. I've double-checked to close the $(documen).ready(function(){, but it still isn't working. Nothing happens when hovering or clicking the image / class.

Comment: @user2021743 With the code you wrote, the hover isn't supposed to trigger the `slideToggle()`. Plus, what do you mean by "isn't working"? Is the `click` event triggered? Is the binding OK? Check that with breakpoints with your firebug JS debugger.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `<script src="script.js"></script>` is the jquery library,
it looks like
you forgot to close the `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".menu_icon").on("click", function(){
        $('.nav').slideToggle();
    });
});
```